# How to do a firebase query that includes empty string as part of the result?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

if i have the following

```
{Books 
       - $firebasekey1
            -dateOfExpiry: "" 
       - $firebasekey2
            -dateOfExpiry:"2016-12-31"
       - $firebasekey3
            -dateOfExpiry:"2015-01-01"
}
```

how do i query all books that have not expired where the result should also include the values `""` i.e. empty string?

i could do something like

```
ref.orderByChild("dateOfExpiry").startAt("2016-12-15").on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.key);
```

but it would not return the items that have `""`(which i require to be included in the result).

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to run two queries:

```
ref.orderByChild("dateOfExpiry").startAt("2016-12-15").on("child_added", function (snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.key);
})
ref.orderByChild("dateOfExpiry").equalTo("").on("child_added", function (snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.key);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to Matthew's answer, you could give the books a default expiration date that is very far into the future:

```
{Books 
   - $firebasekey1
        -dateOfExpiry: "9999-12-31" 
   - $firebasekey2
        -dateOfExpiry:"2016-12-31"
   - $firebasekey3
        -dateOfExpiry:"2015-01-01"
}
```

Then your current, single query would catch all non-expired books.